# how to prevent double time binding data to controls in asp.net with c#

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, postback, asp.net-4.0

i have code to binds data to controls. I prevent them to second time binding when page reloads. It's works with success as ago. but now it's binds double time. i don't know why ?

here is my code :

```
DAL_General obj = new DAL_General();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Fill_Combo();
            Get_Data();
        }
    }
    protected void Fill_Combo()
    {
        DAL_ComboFill obj_u = new DAL_ComboFill();
        obj_u.Fill_Users_Combo(this, ddl_users, false, true);
        obj_u.Fill_SenderIds_Combo(this, ddl_sender, false, true);
        obj_u.Fill_Status_Combo(this, ddl_delevery, false, true);
        obj_u.Fill_AccountType_Combo(this, ddl_account, false, true);
    }
```

and here is my result :
[image]

all drop down list and grid view binds double time. and i want to prevent them. please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Please check with debugging it's call might be two time. and also Check before call Fill_Combo method add condition dropdown items count greater than zero then not call to Fill_Combo() method.

like this

```
if(ddl_users.items.Count == 0)
{
Fill_Combo();
}
```

Comment: ok. and what about grid view. my project all pages have grid view and now it's binds up two time.

Comment: Please check grid view row count. When count available then don't bind to grid.

Comment: not working. I think problem is from database side.

Comment: if you have bind gridview like this                                                                                         GridviewName.ItemSource = _dataset;                                                       So,Please implement this like                                                                                    if(GridviewName?.Rows.Count == 0) {GridviewName.ItemSource = _dataset;                                                       }

Comment: Problem Is that my all page that have gridview bind twice time how ever this not happen in previous time. My page White List Drop Down List works fine and only bind first time records. why this happen??

Comment: I have seen your code after check why it's called twice time but one another approach whenever you bind item source to the grid then please set the first null after bind list to the grid.  lie this                                                    GridView1.DataSource = null;   GridView1.DataSource  = _list;